# checkbox act like radio buttons jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have this jquery and i want my checkbox to act like radio buttons, how can i achive this?

Jquery script:

```
$('[data-toggle="wizard-checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if( $(this).hasClass('active')){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $(this).find('[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $(this).find('[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked','true');
        }
    });
```

Html:

```
<div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-checkbox" rel="tooltip" id="sectiuni" title="Sections">
    <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="sectiuni" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="sectiuni" value="2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="sectiuni" value="3">
</div>
```

Update:

I have images instead of boxes so suggested answers dont work for my current code.  full html code listed below

Full HTML below

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="sectiune">
                            <h4 class="info-text">Va rugam sa alegeti sectiunea pentru momentul dvs.</h4>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-offset" >
                                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset">
                                        <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-checkbox" rel="tooltip" id="sectiuni" title="Solo">
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="solo" name="sectiuni" value="Solo">
                                            <div class="icon">
                                                <img src="assets/img/icons/solo.svg"/>
                                            </div>
                                            <h6>Solo</h6>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset">
                                        <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-checkbox" rel="tooltip" id="sectiuni" title="Duo/Trio/Quartet">
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="duo" name="sectiuni" value="Duo/Trio/Quartet">
                                            <div class="icon">
                                                <img style="width: 48px;" src="assets/img/icons/duotrio.svg"/>
                                            </div>
                                            <h6>Duo/Trio/Quartet</h6>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset">
                                        <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-checkbox" rel="tooltip" id="sectiuni" title="Grupuri 5-12 dansatori">
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="grupuri" name="sectiuni" value="Grupuri">
                                            <div class="icon">
                                                <img style="width: 48px;" src="assets/img/icons/grupuri.png"/>
                                            </div>
                                            <h6>Grupuri</h6>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-checkbox" rel="tooltip" id="sectiuni" title="Formaţii peste 13 dansatori.">
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="formatii" name="sectiuni" value="Formatii">
                                            <div class="icon">
                                                <img style="width: 48px;" src="assets/img/icons/formatii.png"/>
                                            </div>
                                            <h6>Formatii</h6>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Update with success:

I have managed to have-it work! 
See the code below:

```
$('[data-toggle="wizard-checkbox"]').click(function(){
         wizard = $(this).closest('.wizard-card');
         wizard.find('[data-toggle="wizard-checkbox"]').removeClass('active');
                $(wizard).find('[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');

        $(this).find('[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked','true');
        $(this).addClass('active');

    });
```

Comment: If you want checkboxes to behave like checkboxes, why not just use radio buttons? They even have the same `name` attribute. Literally all you need to do is change the `type` to `radio` and delete your JS code for this to work.

Comment: @Alex, while I appreciate your updated code, you have made this is a completely different question. I suggest removing the edit, voting up the answers below for effort (the answers below **did** answer your original question, and then creating a new question. You can't move the goal post after the game has started :-). Lastly, your markup contains duplicate ID's, which will cause all kinds of issues (ID's must be unique). Please fix what you can and post a new question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First off I'll do the obvious thing and strongly suggest that you use this pattern:

```
<input type='radio' name='Same_NAME_as_Sibling_RADs'>
```

That being said, here's how you make a group of checkboxes behave like a radio group:

1. When the change event is triggered on a chx (i.e. checkbox), set ***ALL*** chx in the *default* state:

   - **In this Demo:**

`<input type="checkbox" id="1"`**class**`name="sectiun"value="1"`**disabled=false** **checked=false**>`

2. Ensure that there's only one chx that has a set of properties, attributes, and/or class(es) that defines a state of being active, selected, checked, on, etc.

   - **In this Demo:**

`<input type="checkbox" id="1"`**class="active"**`name="sectiuni"value="1"`**disabled****checked**`>`

3. Having `.active` class set on the `:checked` chx is logical, but what's with the `disabled=true`? This is to emulate radio button's behavior of not being able to be directly toggled into alternating states:

   - **Radio Button Behavior:**

     1. **Click** => Radio is selected all other radio buttons associated by having a common [name] attribute value are now *un*-`:checked`.

        - **[In Demo:** All chx are at default: `checked=false`, `disabled=false`, and `.active` class is removed **]**
     2. **Click it Again** => Radio remains unchanged and it's `:checked` state persists.

        - **[In Demo:** The active chx is actually **disabled** so it will behave exactly like a radio button in active state.
     3. **Click Another One** => Active radio goes to default state, *lather, rinse, repeat....*

### Demo

```js
/*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
On any checkbox having a change event it will...
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {

  /*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ...set all checkboxes as unchecked and ENABLED and remove .active
  At this point nothing is active or selected...
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
  $(':checkbox').prop({
    'checked': false,
    'disabled': false
  }).removeClass('active');

  /*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ...Next check the checkbox that was selected at the origin of 
  the change event (clicked element), disable the checkbox from 
  being manually unchecked, and add .active class.
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
  $(this).prop({
    'checked': true,
    'disabled': true
  }).addClass('active');

});
```

```css
/*+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
This still exixts just not in the DOM. Its influence derives from
the :checked pseudeo-class and its association with a <label>
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/

[type=checkbox] {
  display: none
}


/*+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Each one is associated with an input using pseudo-class :checked. 
A click on the label is the same as clicking the checkbox 
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/

label {
  padding: 21px 15px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
  font: 600 24px/1.2 Conaolas;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  outline: .5px inset rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.active:checked+label {
  background: rgba(72, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="choice" id="sectiuni" title="Sections">

  <!--========================================================
  The <label>'s [for=] attribute associates it with an <input>
  by setting the [for="ID_of_INPUT"] to an #ID of an <input>
  =========================================================-->
  <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="sectiuni" value="1">
  <label for='1'>&#8239;&#8239;&#8239;&#8239;I&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#8239;</label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="sectiuni" value="2">
  <label for='2'>&#8239;&nbsp;&nbsp;II&nbsp;&nbsp;&#8239;</label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="sectiuni" value="3">
  <label for='3'>&#8239;&nbsp;III&nbsp;</label>

</fieldset>




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you @zer00ne ! Very usefull info's